# On a PCB, what does an Earth Ground prong (from a 3-prong plug) connect to?

Tags: pcb-design, grounding

I feel like this is a ridiculous question, but I constantly see examples of projects which are USB-powered, or from a DC power supply, OR using a transformer plug to DC barrel jack. If I am designing a device which handles its own power and I want it to use a 3-prong plug, what does the grounding line connect to?

My understanding is that it would just connect to wherever the GND symbol is, but on simple circuits, that's essentially just the power return. Is that right?

So for example (and *I know this is a ridiculous/non-workable schematic*, but ignore the load for a minute), would it be connected something like this?

[image: Example schematic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Earth/Safety Ground/Protoective Earth wire would normally be connected to exposed metal parts of an appliance. It is intended to hold the exposed metal parts at Ground potential to protect users from shock.

It must not be directly connected to the AC Neutral and is normally not connected to current-carrying parts of the circuit.

If your device has no exposed metal parts, there is no need for a three-wire power cord.

Comment: That makes *so much* more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Should the earth wire be connected to a metal chassis even if that chassis is painted and so not directly exposed? Could you add a clarification of "exposed" to your answer, and a note about removing any coating so that the earth has a sound connection to the chassis? I'm sure your explanation would be more thorough than what I might edit in.

Comment: The official condition for no safety ground is "double insulated" - it would require two insulation faults to give a shock.  I don't think a coat of paint would qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Ground is where anyone wants to call 0V as a reference. This can be a floating power source.

This is often confused with Earth Bonded ground which has safety in mind.  The neutral of a distribution transformer is earth bonded.  So are the copper underground water plumbing and the gas pipeline and a rooftop antenna mast.

The safety details of how earth bonding is done are defined  [here](https://www.ecmweb.com/basics/bonding-grounding/article/20899900/the-basics-of-bonding-and-grounding-transformers).

**For these safety reasons, all-metal appliances and tools are 3 prong safety earth-grounded.**  That includes PC towers but not laptops which use a double-isolated charger, however leakage noise currents up to ~ 100uA  can be felt on the wrist or knee if you are on wet grass or floor with humidity. That is because of the CLC or "Pi" filter with RF caps to earth ground.

Plastic "double insulated" tools, radios and isolated transformer or SMPS driven LEDs are not earth-grounded.

The ground fault leakage current interruptors or GFCI's do not actually measure ground leakage currents, but rather the small differential between Line and Neutral if are not balanced perfectly they interrupt power with a very sensitive common-mode current relay.